# Setting up jenkins on centos: problems with ssh keys and git

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins, centos, ssh-keys

Went through a lot of questions, but nothing seems to be solving my issue. Or to be more precise I am not sure if I am doing the whole thing correctly.
So here it is:

Have installed centos 6.3 OS.
Then I followed the following guide to install jenkins:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+RedHat+distributions

Jenkins works fine. Now I am trying to set up a simple build job, which requires to clone a git repository. (I've installed git plugin)

In repository URL i type the following:
git@gitserver:myrepo.git
Of course I get an error: stderr: Host key verification failed.

ok, I need to generate ssh keys and all will be good. 
So I do the following:

```
su - jenkins
```

but unfortunately it doesn't switch to jenkins user.

cat /etc/passwd

shows the following:

```
jenkins:x:496:492:Jenkins Continuous Build Server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/false
```

so seems that it doesn't have a usual home directory.

The question is how do I generate keys for jenkins or if the above steps where not the right way to do it, how do I fix it?

Thanks a lot!

**Update**:
I generated keys (as a root user) and placed them in jenkins home and did exactly and copied public key to git server. Still didn't help.

When I look at the log of the build it says:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myrepo/workspace
```

this user anonymous is this another user created by jenkins, or is it still jenkins that runs  the commands?

Comment: I am getting same problem :(.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming that you have root access if you were able to install the Jenkins RPM.  Were you su-ing to the jenkins user while logged in as root ?  If not, you should do so or use

```
sudo su - jenkins
```

if your logged in user has sudo access.

Then run

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

to generate an RSA keypair for the jenkins user, and you can upload the public key to your git server.  The key will be generated as /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh.id_ra.pub if you take the defaults.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't switch to jenkins home. Still stays in my users home. But I still generated keys as a root user in jenkins home and did exactly as you've said, but the error still persists.

Comment: Hmm, I misformatted my sudo command above - just corrected that.

Comment: Is it correct, that the key file's owner is root? Probably the jenkins user has no login shell and that can be the cause. Check the `/etc/passwd` file for an entry like `jenkins:x:999:1001::/var/lib/jenkins:/sbin/nologin` and change the `/sbin/nologin` with `/bin/bash` temporarily to switch to user jenkins.

Comment: Run ssh-keygen with sudo for jenkins but without su i.e. `sudo -u jenkins ssh-keygen` when the jenkins user has no login shell as in the Centos RPM setup.

Answer (score 5):

1 change user jenkins login setting

vi /etc/passwd

update /bin/false to /bin/bash

2 su - jenkins

jekins user home would be /var/lib/jenkins

3 ssh-keygen

cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub

copy this key to bitbucket

4 ssh git@bitbucket.org

this is going to set the bitbucket ssh key in .ssh/known_hosts

Now you should be able to access

Answer (score 2):

I think the .ssh directory should live in /var/lib/jenkins.

Works for me

Comment: indeed it is there. But it was empty.
What I did I generated keys in that directory. Took public key and appended to authorized_keys file on git server. Still doesn't work...

Answer (score 2):

I was having problems changing to the jenkins user. I needed to actually create the user properly in the system so I could log in to it. I ran this command to help me create the jenkins user in the system:

```
su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

Answer (score 2):

1) First make jenkins as real user by editing /etc/passwd file
 Change

> /bin/false to /bin/bash

2) Login to jenkins user, Now Jenkins home directory will be /var/lib/jenkins

```
su - jenkins
```

3)Generate ssh keys again ( keys will be created in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

4) copy id_rsa.pub key and paste in your git's authorized_keys file

5) Still if it won't work, probably you have to check permissions of your .ssh directory and contents

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```

Answer (score 2):

jenkins is a service account, it doesn't have a shell by design. It is generally accepted that service accounts shouldn't be able to log in interactively.

I didn't answer this one initially as it's a duplicate of a question that has been moved to server fault. I should have answered rather than linked to the answer in a comment.

if for some reason you want to login as jenkins, you can do so with: **sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins**

Answer (score 1):

In order to login as "jenkins" user, maybe you could try this:

```
sudo -s -H -u jenkins
```

And try to invoke:

```
bash-4.1$ whoami
jenkins
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I did: sudo -u jenkins ssh-keygen. It works so far