# Jenkins - SSH Repository URL unable to connect

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins in CentOS and also installed git plugin so as to use Bitbucket. When adding Repository URL in Source Code Management, HTTPS works good but when I add SSH url the following error pops up -

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:ash_dy/test_1.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Host key verification failed. 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have googled for this but didn't find any answers to my problem, I would like to use ssh rather than Https so please help.

Comment: Does git user has password-less access via keys or you key in password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found solution for my problem, I am posting it here for others.

1. Configure the shell for the jenkins user by editing `/etc/passwd`/ and changing `/bin/false` to `/bin/bash`.
2. `su - jenkins`. Note the jenkins user's home is `/var/lib/jenkins`
3. `ssh-keygen` then `cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub` and copy this key to your bitbucket account
4. `ssh git@bitbucket.org` to set the bitbucket ssh key in .ssh/known_hosts

Now you should be able to access bitbucket from Jenkins.

Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599077/setting-up-jenkins-on-centos-problems-with-ssh-keys-and-git?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Try to log as jenkins user on your machine. Then execute:

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

This command will verify your ssh configuration between you and bitbucket. Perhaps your ssh key is not the good one.

Comment: I am using windows, it doesnt have a jenkins user, is that correct or I missed something ?